# How do I create an AppleScript file using NSAppleScript?

Tags: cocoa, applescript

My code looks like this:

```
NSMutableString* cmd = [NSMutableString new];
[cmd appendString:@"script createScriptFile\n"];
[cmd appendString:@"beep\n"];
[cmd appendString:@"end script\n"];
[cmd appendString:@"store script createScriptFile in \"/tmp/narg.scpt\"\n"];
NSAppleScript* script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:cmd];
NSDictionary* err = nil;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [script executeAndReturnError:&err];
```

which runs fine without errors, but the resulting script file (narg.scpt) looks like this:

```
script createScriptFile
beep
end script
store script createScriptFile in "/tmp/narg.scpt"
```

and what I want is for narg.sctp to look like this:

```
beep
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Are you sure?  When I run the example you give from the AppleScript editor, the contents of "/tmp/narg.scpt" are "beep" as you expect.

Comment: Ugh. If you _genuinely_ need to generate AppleScripts on the fly, the simplest approach is to pipe the source code as UTF8 data to `osacompile`. If you must do it in-process, use OSAKit, which provides most of the features missing from NSAppleScript (it's what AppleScript Editor users). It's undocumented, so you'll need to read the headers for usage, but not too hard to figure out.